# How to cast earth datatype to json in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, casting, earthdistance

I want to cast the earth datatype to a json array in Postgresql (9.5).

This is what I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION earth_to_json (inpt earth)
RETURNS json AS $$
    SELECT json_build_array(latitude(inpt), longitude(inpt))
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE CAST (earth AS JSON) WITH FUNCTION earth_to_json(earth) AS IMPLICIT;
```

When executing the query above, I get the following output:

```
WARNING: cast will be ignored because the source data type is a domain 
CREATE CAST 
Query returned successfully in 47 msec.
```

So the `earth` datatype is domain, according to the message above. I know earthdistance is based on the cube module, but I assumed the `earth` datatype is a real datatype so I should be able to cast.

So if above code should work, the code below should run fine.

```
SELECT ll_to_earth(10.10, 30.01)::JSON
```

But I get the error

```
 ERROR: cannot cast type earth to json LINE 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What I found out:

The `earth` datatype is not a real datatype. This is the type cube, with constraints (constraints are defined in the earth-domain). So I really need to create a cast which casts the cube datatype to json.

When you accidentally have a cube with fits in the earth domain, it will be returned as `lat, lon` array. You could create your own datatype to work around this. For me this works ok, as I do not use the cube datatype.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cube_to_json (inpt cube)
RETURNS json AS $$
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        RETURN json_build_array(latitude(inpt), longitude(inpt));
    EXCEPTION WHEN SQLSTATE '23514' THEN
        RETURN CASE WHEN json_array_length(sub) = 1 THEN sub->0 ELSE sub END FROM (SELECT translate('[' || inpt::TEXT || ']', '()', '[]')::JSON AS sub) AS o;
    END;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE CAST (cube AS json) WITH FUNCTION cube_to_json(cube) AS IMPLICIT
-- Now test
SELECT (ll_to_earth(10,20))::JSON; -- Outputs [10,20]
SELECT ('(5437508.36471516, 3140612.41127573), (118.44062468, 1)'::CUBE)::JSON; -- Outputs "[[5437508.36471516, 3140612.41127573], [118.44062468, 1]]"
```